# I have a rectangle with given dimensions.How do I calculate the dimensions of a rectangle that is 60% of given rectangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Rectangle is 60 sq inches with sides 10 x 6"

I need to draw a rectangle that is 60% of given rectangle.
How do I calculate side lengths for new rectangle?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you done so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: I assume you mean $60\%$ of the area. If so, this question is clearly lacking something... there are *infinitely many* such rectangles.

Comment: Did you just mean 60% of the area? if so you want something that is $0.6 \cdot 60 = 36$ sq. inches, which has many different possible ways to draw. $ h \times w = 36$ has infinite solutions.

Comment: What is the formula for the area of the larger rectangle?  For the smaller rectangle?  What is the expression showing the relationship between those areas?  What common variables show up in these equations?

Comment: This question seems to fall into the category of geometry  rather than linear algebra.

Answer (score 3):

If you intend to find a rectangle with $60\%$ of the area, then you want to find a rectangle with $0.6 \times 60 = 36$ sq. inches area. This can be expressed by $h \times w = 36$, which has one equation and two unknowns, so it has infinite solutions.

To find a solution, rearrange so one variable is on each side, i.e. $h = \frac{36}{w}$. Now given any width, dividing $36$ by that width will give you a height such that the area of the rectangle formed is 36 sq. inches or $60\%$ of the original rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

If you want each linear dimension to be $60\%$ of the starting rectangle, it is $(10 \cdot 0.6) \times (6 \cdot 0.6)=6 \times 3.6$ inches.  If you want $60\%$ of the area, maintaining the aspect ratio, you want $(10 \cdot \sqrt{0.6}) \times (6 \cdot \sqrt{0.6}) \approx 7.75 \times 4.65$.  It is important to formulate your question carefully.